# Y-axis of the reaction co-ordinate graph

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, notation, reaction-coordinate

In the graph of the reaction co-ordinate, is the $y$-axis that is used  $∆H,$ $∆U$ or $∆G$?

Comment: Energy, the context depends on what type.

Comment: Generally it is energy

Comment: Why though and what exactly does ∆U represent here. Like what's the difference between ∆U and ∆H , on terms of a reaction

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_coordinate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_profile_(chemistry)

Comment: Single molecules have no entropy, so Gibbs makes no sense. If you want to use a molar quantity, it's ∆H.

Answer (score 4):

**Single molecule reaction**

Some diagrams refer to a single molecule reacting. If that is the case, several quantities are not defined or ill-defined:

- pressure
- entropy of mixing
- temperature

In those diagrams, the best label would be potential energy, and the energy difference between reactant and transition state should be labeled activation energy.

**Ensemble reaction**

If the diagram refers to an ensemble reacting (reaction mixture with sufficient number of molecules to have macroscopic properties), the y-axis could correspond to Gibbs energy, enthalpy or internal energy.

If the y-axis represents Gibbs energy, the energy difference between reactant and transition state should be labeled $\Delta G^\ddagger$. Those diagrams make sense when discussing how equilibrium constants remain unchanged but reaction rates change when a catalyst is added.

If the y-axis represents enthalpy or internal energy, the energy difference between reactant and transition state should be labeled $E_a$ for activation energy. Those diagrams make sense when discussing reaction rates in the context of collision theory.

**What is most popular?**

Looking at about 50 images of reaction energy diagrams found in a google image search, I found a wide variety, and lots of mixing and matching (i.e. incompatible quantities in a single diagram). This tells you that the diagram is conceptual, and the concepts are not always clearly articulated in diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

Following is an example of Reaction Coordinate Diagram. I labelled all necessary details for your convenient. Please note that the *Blue* path is for the same reaction when catalyst is involved. The difference is the activation energy, which is lower in the presence of a catalyst.

[image: Rxn Coordinates]