# Kinetics Vs Thermodynamics : Apparent contradiction in the definition of Enthalpy in the two disciplines

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics, enthalpy

My book gives the following curve:

[image]

It gives the following relation :$$ΔH= E_{\mathrm{activation,forward}}-E_{\mathrm{activation,backward}} \tag{1}$$

But I suspect that $ E_{\mathrm{activation,forward}}-E_{\mathrm{activation,backward}}$ corresponds to change in Internal Energy of the system ΔU.

or $$ΔU= E_{\mathrm{activation,forward}}-E_{\mathrm{activation,backward}} \tag{2}$$

However,at a constant pressure, heat of reaction or Enthalpy change $$ΔH = ΔU + PΔV \tag{3}$$

Statement (3) contradicts statements (1) and (2) or is valid only for $ΔV=0$

---

This source contains the same graph : https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/18%3A_Kinetics/18.04%3A_Potential_Energy_Diagrams

---

What is going on here?

In case, you feel that the graph is given only to cover a particular kind of reaction, please provide relevant comments.

Comment: Your book is sloppy?

Comment: @Zhe It does contain some misprints but overall it is a very good book for undergraduates. Moreover I have seen similar graphs in other books and on internet like https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/18%3A_Kinetics/18.04%3A_Potential_Energy_Diagrams

Comment: Instead of using what appears to be the Arrhenius equation, trying looking at the Eyring equation instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyring_equation

Comment: @Zhe Sir I am just an undergrad and Erying equation seems a little beyond my understanding. Please explain what are you trying to convey here through this equation.

Comment: The Eyring equation is from modern transition state theory. The Arrhenius equation is a fine starting point, and shares some similar features.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/115923/72973

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason might be that while drawing the reaction energy profile, we forget to mention what energy we are mentioning in the Y-axis. The following conventions are generally used:

- If reaction conditions are constant NVT, energy in Y-axis should represent internal energy.
- If reaction conditions are constant NPT, energy in Y-axis should represent enthalpy.
- If reaction conditions are constant $\mu$VT, energy in Y-axis should represent Helmholtz free energy.
- If reaction conditions are constant $\mu$PT, energy in Y-axis should represent Gibbs free energy.
- If you are looking at single molecule, the energy will be the total energy of the molecule (kinetic energy + potential energy).

In case of reactions, the last three are generally used.

Hence, the "Energy" Y-axis changes based on reaction conditions. In the question, it seems you might have got mixed up somehow.

---

Summary of the terms used:

- N: No of molecules
- $\mu$: Chemical potential
- V: Volume
- P: Pressure
- T: Temperature

Comment: Refer to NCERT Chemistry Class 12 Part 1 - Chemical Kinetics page 112 Graph 4.7 . It clearly mentions Potential Energy to Y-axis.

Comment: Even here they are deliberately using Potential Energy on the Y-axis along with same Enthalpy representation https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/18%3A_Kinetics/18.04%3A_Potential_Energy_Diagrams

Comment: Please refrain from using a footnote that adds nothing to the answer. They can only reply *in* the comments and a greeting/footnote is unnecessary(adding very little value) in a Q&A forum.

Comment: So are you saying that in the Y-axis of my diagram,it should contain Enthalpy?

Comment: @TonyStark The Y axis is dependent on reaction conditions. You cannot expect to use Helmholtz free energy while studying reaction in $\mu$PT conditions.

Comment: Also, the Arrhenius activation energy is not equal to $\Delta^\neq H^\circ$. For a bimolecular reaction according to transition-state theory, $E_a =\Delta^\neq H^\circ +  2RT $, for a bimolecular reaction.